# How to interpret list of jobs returned from get_jobs in APScheduler?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am trying to figure out whether APScheduler is the tool for my project's needs.

I can add a job.

I can get a list of jobs -- but I am having trouble interpreting the results.  I want to have my program translate this returned job list into a format needed by other parts of the program.  I need to extract the trigger parameters.

Let's say I'm using a cron trigger.  I'll make a simple one for now:

```
new_job = self.scheduler.add_job(jobfunc,'cron', minute='*/5', args=["minute"]
```

Later, I want to get the jobs and then extract the basic information (this is a cron trigger, that it is scheduled for 'minute'=*/5) -- basically I want to reconstruct the parameters with which I created the trigger.

I have looked at the jobs returned in the debugger, and I see that each job has a "trigger" member which has within it the information I need -- but I am not sure how to access it programmatically.

I would like to do something like this:

```
    jobs=self.scheduler.get_jobs()
    schedules=[]
    for job in jobs:
        schedules.append(<do something with job.trigger.fields>)
```

Where the element appended to schedules would look something like:

```
{'minute':'*/5'}
```

The documentation says:

> To get a machine processable list of the scheduled jobs, you can use the get_jobs().

The question is, how should my 'machine' process this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, thanks to a previously asked question on the APScheduler Google group, I have a solution!

The details have to be accessed through the fields, as I thought.  The key to get the information from the individual field is to convert the field value to a string.

Here is an example which works:

```
 schedules = []
 for job in self.scheduler.get_jobs():
     jobdict = {}
     for f in job.trigger.fields:
         curval = str(f)
         jobdict[f.name] = curval

     schedules.append(jobdict)
```

For a schedule with one job added as:

```
new_job = self.scheduler.add_job(jobfunc,'cron', second='*/5', args=["second"])
```

The resulting list comes out like this:

```
[{'week': '*', 'hour': '*', 'day_of_week': '*', 'month': '*', 'second': '*/5', 'year': '*', 'day': '*', 'minute': '*'}]
```

Comment: The above only works with cron triggers, interval triggers do not have a field attribute

Answer (score 5):

Putting this here for anyone who is trying to find different attrs of their Job object.
Since the object doesn't utilize `__dict__` use `__slots__` instead. This will show you all the different attributes of the Job Object just as `__dict__` would.

```python
>>> scheduler.get_jobs()[0].__slots__
('_scheduler', '_jobstore_alias', 'id', 'trigger', 'executor', 'func', 'func_ref', 'args', 'kwargs', 'name', 'misfire_grace_time', 'coalesce', 'max_instances', 'next_run_time', '__weakref__')
```

Then with this information you can then retrieve the attrs

```python
>>> scheduler.get_jobs()[0].trigger
<IntervalTrigger (interval=datetime.timedelta(seconds=1200), start_date='2021-08-06 10:01:19 CDT', timezone='America/Chicago')>
>>> scheduler.get_jobs()[0].max_instances
1
```

Comment: Does the `__slots__` exist also for scheduler? How could I see the attributes of scheduler? Thanks.

Comment: I would like to get some sort of scheduler pid so I can stop him as needed.

Comment: @vpap Ideally you would do so from python itself, I can't think of a reason that you would need the pid of the scheduler. If anything, you should use the shutdown class method on the scheduler object in order to stop it. i.e. `scheduler.shutdown()`

Comment: I am starting the scheduler from a web UI and unfortunately after any scheduler initialization and calling `start()` basically there's no direct way to track it. For now, I am solving this problem by using its id w/ `id(scheduler)`.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks interesting; I'm not working with APScheduler for years already though, so I can not confirm it.

Answer (score 3):

APScheduler `.get_jobs()` method returns a list of job instances.

For example, you can print information about all currently scheduled jobs with something like the following:

```
for job in scheduler.get_jobs():
    print("name: %s, trigger: %s, next run: %s, handler: %s" % (
          job.name, job.trigger, job.next_run_time, job.func))
```

Note that job names can repeat across different jobs.

You can find here the [API reference for the `job` class](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/job.html#module-apscheduler.job). It doesn't explicitly list the job class members, but they match the variables in *kwargs*.