# Access APScheduler cron trigger field values in python

Tags: python, apscheduler, crontrigger

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400456/how-to-interpret-list-of-jobs-returned-from-get-jobs-in-apscheduler) I want to extract the info of a cron job trigger from APScheduler.
However, I need the "day_of_week" field and not everything. Using

```
for job in scheduler.get_jobs():
  for f in job.trigger.fields:
    print(f.name + " " + str(f))
```

i can see all the fields, e.g. `week,hour,day_of_week` , but

`job.trigger.day_of_week` is seemingly 'not an attribute' of the "CronTrigger" object. I'm confused as to what kind of object this `job.trigger` is and how its fields are packed. I tried to read the code on github, but it is even more puzzling.

How do I extract only the one field `day_of_week`, and how is this trigger class structured?

Diving deeper I found that

```
apscheduler.triggers.cron.fields.DayOfWeekField
```

I can find by indexing the `job.trigger.fields[4]`, which seems really bad style, since it depends on the 'position'of the field. What I get is this DayOfWeekField, from which comically I am not able to retrieve it's value either:

```
a.get_value
<bound method DayOfWeekField.get_value of DayOfWeekField('day_of_week', '1,2,3,4')>
```

The structure of the fields is coded [here](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/apscheduler/triggers/cron/fields.py), but I don't know what to do with dateval, the argument of `get_value()`.

Eventually, after hopefully understanding the concept, I want to do

```
if job-day_of_week contains mon

if job-day_of_week == '*'

print ( job-day_of_week )
```

I am grateful for any suggestions/hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, you should be able to get the `day_of_week` field without hardcoding the index by using the `CronTrigger` class's `FIELD_NAMES` property, e.g.

```
dow_index = CronTrigger.FIELD_NAMES.index('day_of_week')
dow = job.trigger.fields[dow_index]
```

Getting the value of the field is a bit more complicated, but it appears that `BaseField` implements the *str* function that should give you the value of the expression that created the field as a string that you could parse to find what you want:

```
dow_value_as_string = str(dow)
if 'mon' in dow_value_as_string:
   # do something
if dow_value_as_string = "*":
   # do something else
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! Could you just elaborate a little bit, how this FIELD_NAMES property and the indexing works? Why are the fields of CronTrigger ordered - is this python itself?

Comment: FIELD_NAMES is a property of the CronTrigger class which is defined [here.](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/apscheduler/triggers/cron/__init__.py).  (It's explicitly defined in the code, not some sort of built-in python magic. ) The property is a list of field names and the `index` function is a built-in for lists, returning the index of the first occurrence of 'day_of_week' in the list.